# jQuery heights on images not possible after ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, height

Currently have a function to determine the highest image height to set the minimum height of the image container element, in this case a figure.

The function works fine on window load and if the window is resized. However the result from the function after an ajax call loads content into my target div just returns '0'. I've read that I may be getting image dimensions too quickly which is why it's returning '0' but don't know how to amend properly.

How do I wait until images have loaded before applying my function on ajax success (if that's what the problem is!)?

JAVASCRIPT

```
// Get the highest image to use as the minimum Figure <figure> height
function minFigureHeight() {
var imgs = $('.property-image > img');
var maxImgHeight = 0;
  imgs.each(function () {
      var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
      maxImgHeight = maxImgHeight > imgHeight ? maxImgHeight :   imgHeight;
  });
return maxImgHeight
}

// When the window loads add a min-height style to the Figure <figure>
$(window).load(function() {
   var newHeight = minFigureHeight();
   $('.property-image').css("min-height", newHeight);
});

// If the window resizes recalculate and add a min-height style to the Figure <figure>
$(window).resize(function(){
  var newHeight = minFigureHeight();
  $('.property-image').css("min-height", newHeight);
});
```

HTML

```
<article class="property">
  <figure class="property-image">
    <img src="images/36048_BAO150030_IMG_00.JPG" alt="Any Street" />
  </figure>
  <div class="property-details">
    <p>2 Bedroomed House</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

HTML after function is run (Working Correctly)

```
<article class="property">
  <figure class="property-image" style="min-height: 240px">
    <img src="images/36048_BAO150030_IMG_00.JPG" alt="Any Street" />
  </figure>
  <div class="property-details">
    <p>2 Bedroomed House</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

AJAX

```
$('#filter-search').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent native submit
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#mytarget',
        url: '/search_ajax', 
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
          var newHeight = minFigureHeight();
          $('.property-image').css("min-height", newHeight);
        }
    });  
});
```

HTML after function runs on successful ajax call (Not working)

```
<article class="property">
  <figure class="property-image" style="min-height: 0px">
    <img src="images/36048_BAO150030_IMG_00.JPG" alt="Any Street" />
  </figure>
  <div class="property-details">
    <p>2 Bedroomed House</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `minFigureHeight()` only if the `image` has been fully loaded.
Did not test this but something like this in the `success` callback should work.

```
$('#filter-search').on('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent native submit
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        target: '#mytarget',
        url: '/search_ajax', 
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
            /* 
                Get the prefered image source
                and create an image for preloading.
            */
            var img = $('.property-image > img'),
                src = img.attr('src'),
                image = new Image();
            /* wait for image to be loaded */
            image.onload = function() {
                var newHeight = minFigureHeight();
                $('.property-image').css("min-height", newHeight);           
            };
            /* set the image src */
            image.src = src;

        }
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**Two things:**

1. Your function is firing before your image is loaded. Images are loaded asynchronously and ajax's `success:` does not ensure that the image has been loaded.

You need to use `load` in the function. However, since just `load` on images doesn't work on all browsers, the following is a trick that triggers the load on `complete` thus making it browser compatible.

```
var newHeight = minFigureHeight();
$('.property-image img').css("min-height", newHeight);


// Get the highest image to use as the minimum Figure <figure> height
function minFigureHeight() {
var imgs = $('.property-image > img');
var maxImgHeight = 0;

  imgs.one('load',function(){ 
      var imgHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
      maxImgHeight = maxImgHeight > imgHeight ? maxImgHeight :   imgHeight;
  }).each(function() {
      if(this.complete) $(this).load();
  });
return maxImgHeight
}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/odhanooy/

2. Shouldn't `min-height` be applied to the `img` and not the `div`?